# Connect phpMyAdmin docker image to the HOST MySQL server listening only on 127.0.0.1

Tags: mysql, docker, networking, phpmyadmin, local

I am looking to connect a PhpMyAdmin running in a container (Docker) to a MySQL server running on the host and listening on 127.0.0.1.

However, when I give docker the varuable -e PMA_HOST=127.0.0.1, it only look on it's own Docker network... How would I be able to talk to my host MySQL DB server ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use `127.0.0.1` as IP address to refer to the host as that will point to the docker container where phpAdmin is running.

You need to find the IP address of the host on the `docker0` interface as use that ip instead. You can do that using:

```
-e PMA_HOST=$(ip route show | grep docker0 | awk '{print $9}')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your mysql is on your host, without a domain name, you won't be able to access it from a container. Maybe with a bridged network. 
You should try to move the database to a container. It will be super easy to connect the phpmyadmin then.